# Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

Hello I am new to the Algorithms and trying to understand the Minimum Spanning Trees.

I study the "Introduction to Algorithms" book by Cormen,Leiserson,Rivest and Stein. I have had a hard problem in understanding the sentence ".. a cut **respects** a set A of edges if no edge in A crosses the cut."

Let me clear my understanding by putting the pictures from the given example.
[A minimum spanning tree for a connected graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snSKX.png)

[1 way of viewing a cut (S,V-S) of the previous graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWlq7.png)

So my question is when we cut the graph as shown by the second figure shouldn't we also shade the edge (d,e) since it does not cross the cut ?

I would appreciate if you clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is kruskal's MST algorithm i think. Cut just partitions every subtree from the rest of the subtrees. We need to use the idea of the cut because when we join two subtrees we want no cycle and also the edge with minimum cost between those two subtrees.

In you image the cost of **(d,e)** is **9** so it's not a subtree. You can think of it as a not evaluated edge.  Your subtrees are **(a,b) and (i,c,f,g,h)** so a cut must differentiate these subtrees from other edges.

The shaded edges means that they are for sure in MST because they have minimum cost.

Here is just painted picture of your algorithm:

In the first iteration you get first cut **black** because the edge **(g,h)** has the minimum cost. Then you get red cut because after **(g,h)** gf has the minimum cost and because these two subtrees are attached to each other we use one cut. and so on ... I hope you can execute it further.You can see here visualization how [Kruskal's](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskals_algoritme) algorithm works.

[image]